Error adding chat history to LangChain Angular component
I am trying to connect my Angular front-end to a LangChain Agent Executor.   I presently receive the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 375, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 226, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 159, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langserve/server.py", line 481, in invoke
    return await api_handler.invoke(request)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langserve/api_handler.py", line 729, in invoke
    output = await self._runnable.ainvoke(input_, config=config)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 4523, in ainvoke
    return await self.bound.ainvoke(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 212, in ainvoke
    raise e
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 203, in ainvoke
    await self._acall(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1481, in _acall
    next_step_output = await self._atake_next_step(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1275, in _atake_next_step
    [
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1275, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1303, in _aiter_next_step
    output = await self.agent.aplan(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 436, in aplan
    async for chunk in self.runnable.astream(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 2900, in astream
    async for chunk in self.atransform(input_aiter(), config, **kwargs):
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 2883, in atransform
    async for chunk in self._atransform_stream_with_config(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 1984, in _atransform_stream_with_config
    chunk = cast(Output, await py_anext(iterator))
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 2853, in _atransform
    async for output in final_pipeline:
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 1316, in atransform
    async for chunk in input:
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 4734, in atransform
    async for item in self.bound.atransform(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 1333, in atransform
    async for output in self.astream(final, config, **kwargs):
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 315, in astream
    raise e
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py", line 293, in astream
    async for chunk in self._astream(
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_openai/chat_models/base.py", line 601, in _astream
    message_dicts, params = self._create_message_dicts(messages, stop)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_openai/chat_models/base.py", line 559, in _create_message_dicts
    message_dicts = [_convert_message_to_dict(m) for m in messages]
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_openai/chat_models/base.py", line 559, in <listcomp>
    message_dicts = [_convert_message_to_dict(m) for m in messages]
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_openai/chat_models/base.py", line 205, in _convert_message_to_dict
    raise TypeError(f"Got unknown type {message}")
TypeError: Got unknown type content='How do you make a peanut butter sandwich?' type='human' name='message7705fa63-9eb4-41ff-b294-9023da12ae81' id='7705fa63-9eb4-41ff-b294-9023da12ae81'

I'm not sure how to move forward to avoid the TypeError(f"Got unknown type {message}")
Using the Pydantic JSON schema specs, I have created an input model that looks like the following:
export  interface  AgentInput {
chat_history:  BaseMessage[];
input:  string;
[property:  string]:  any;
}

export  interface  BaseMessage {
additional_kwargs?: { [key:  string]:  any };
content:  Array<{ [key:  string]:  any } |  string> |  string;
id?:  string;
name?:  string;
response_metadata?: { [key:  string]:  any };
type:  string;
[property:  string]:  any;
}

I use this class to represent the chat messages in the UX
import { BaseMessage } from  "./agent-input";

export  class  ChatMessage  implements  BaseMessage {
id:  string  =  '';
type:  string  =  '';
name:  string  =  '';
content:  string  | (string  | { [key:  string]:  any; })[];
additional_kwargs?: { [key:  string]:  any; } |  undefined;
response_metadata?: { [key:  string]:  any; } |  undefined;
[property:  string]:  any;

constructor(
contentInput:  string,
messageType:  string
) {
this.content  =  contentInput.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
const  guid  =  this.generateGUID();
this.id  =  guid;
this.type  =  messageType;
this.name  =  "message"  +  this.id;
}

generateGUID():  string {
    // return guid 
});

}

}

Agent Service
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from  "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from  "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from  "rxjs";
import { ChatMessage } from  "./bot1/chat-message";
import { AgentInput } from  "./bot1/agent-input";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export  class  AgentService {

constructor(private http:  HttpClient) { }

postQuery(query:  string, chatHistory:  ChatMessage[]):  Observable<any> {

const  url  =  '/agent/invoke';
 
const  data  = {
input: {
input: query,
chat_history: chatHistory
},
config: {},
kwargs: {}
} as  unknown  as  AgentInput; 

const  headers  =  new  HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
return  this.http.post(url, data, { headers });
}

}

If I do not populate the "chat_history" collection on input, the agent executor responds properly.  If I provide a chat history message, I receive the error stated above.
What are the valid values that I should be providing to the "type" attribute of the BaseMessage?
If anyone has examples of using LangChain agent executor from an Angular service, that would be helpful.
Thank you in advance for your time.
